# How draw this game in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the two following picture in Tikz and insert in my LaTeX document, any ready code would be appreciated[image].[image]

Please note that the context of these pictures are game theory and extensive form games.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a straightforward recreation of the first:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\coordinate (x5) at (-3, 2);
\coordinate (x1) at ( 0, 2);
\coordinate (x3) at ( 3, 2);
\coordinate (x6) at (-3, -2);
\coordinate (x2) at ( 0, -2);
\coordinate (x4) at ( 3, -2);
\coordinate (r1) at (-5, 3);
\coordinate (r2) at (-5, 1);
\coordinate (r3) at (-5, -1);
\coordinate (r4) at (-5, -3);
\coordinate (r5) at ( 5, 3);
\coordinate (r6) at ( 5, 1);
\coordinate (r7) at ( 5, -1);
\coordinate (r8) at ( 5, -3);
\coordinate (o) at (-1.25, 0);
\node[circle, draw, inner sep=0.15em] (oc) at (o) {};
\node[anchor=north west] at (x1) {$x_1$};
\node[anchor=north west] at (x5) {$x_5$};
\node[anchor=north east] at (x3) {$x_3$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (x2) {$x_2$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (x6) {$x_6$};
\node[anchor=south east] at (x4) {$x_4$};
\node[anchor=east] at (r1) {3, 0};
\node[anchor=east] at (r2) {3, 2};
\node[anchor=east] at (r3) {0, 3};
\node[anchor=east] at (r4) {3, 2};
\node[anchor=west] at (r5) {2, 3};
\node[anchor=west] at (r6) {2, 2};
\node[anchor=west] at (r7) {2, 3};
\node[anchor=west] at (r8) {2, 2};
\node[anchor=north east] at (o) {Nature};
\draw[->] (oc.75) -- (x1) node[midway, anchor=east] {[.5]1};
\draw[->] (oc.285) -- (x2) node[midway, anchor=east] {[.5]2};
\draw[->] (x1) -- (x3) node[midway, anchor=south] {Average};
\draw[->] (x1) -- (x5) node[midway, anchor=south] {Hunk\vphantom{g}};
\draw[->] (x2) -- (x4) node[midway, anchor=north] {Average};
\draw[->] (x2) -- (x6) node[midway, anchor=north] {Hunk};
\draw[->] (x5) -- (r1) node[near end, anchor=south west] {Hunk};
\draw[->] (x5) -- (r2) node[near end, anchor=north west] {Average};
\draw[->] (x6) -- (r3) node[near end, anchor=south west] {Hunk};
\draw[->] (x6) -- (r4) node[near end, anchor=north west] {Average};
\draw[->] (x3) -- (r5) node[near end, anchor=south east] {Hunk};
\draw[->] (x3) -- (r6) node[near end, anchor=north east] {Average};
\draw[->] (x4) -- (r7) node[near end, anchor=south east] {Hunk};
\draw[->] (x4) -- (r8) node[near end, anchor=north east] {Average};
\draw[dashed] (x5) -- (x6) node[pos=0.45, anchor=east] {Tina} node[pos=0.45, anchor=west] {$h_{T2}$};
\draw[dashed] (x3) -- (x4) node[midway, anchor=west] {Tina} node[midway, anchor=east] {$h_{T1}$};
\draw[dashed] (x1) -- (x2) node[midway, anchor=west] {Gina} node[midway, anchor=east] {$h_G$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- You can tweak the coordinates to move the various nodes around --- I've named them according to their labels (`r1` ... `r8` are `r`esults, `o` is the `o`rigin, `oc` the `o`rigin `c`ircle).
- Edge labels are mostly positioned `midway`, but I've manually moved one using `pos=...` to make the whole thing look better (`midway` is equivalent to `pos=0.5` FWIW).
- `>=Stealth` in changes the default arrow tips to the `Stealth` tips from the `arrows.meta` Ti*k*Z library (which must be loaded for this to work).
- I've used a `\vphantom{g}` in one of the edge labels to make sure the different depths of "Hunk" and "Average" do not lead to uneven placement of those labels.

**EDIT:** and of the second:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\coordinate (x5) at (-2,  2);
\coordinate (x1) at ( 0,  2);
\coordinate (x3) at ( 2,  2);
\coordinate (x6) at (-2, -2);
\coordinate (x2) at ( 0, -2);
\coordinate (x4) at ( 2, -2);
\coordinate (r1) at (-3,  3);
\coordinate (r2) at (-3,  1);
\coordinate (r3) at (-3, -1);
\coordinate (r4) at (-3, -3);
\coordinate (o)  at ( 0,  0);
\coordinate (rl) at (-2.5, -0.5);
\node[anchor=north west] at (x1) {$x_u$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (x2) {$x_d$};
\node[anchor=south, yshift=0.75em] at (x1) {2};
\node[anchor=north] at (x2) {2};
\node[anchor=west] at (x3) {1, 1};
\node[anchor=west] at (x4) {1, 1};
\node[anchor=east] at (r1) {1, 2};
\node[anchor=east] at (r2) {0, 0};
\node[anchor=east] at (r3) {2, 0};
\node[anchor=east] at (r4) {1, 0};
\node[anchor=west, xshift=0.75em] at (o) {Nature};
\draw[->] (o) -- (x1) node[midway, anchor=east] {[.5]} node[midway, anchor=west] {U};
\draw[->] (o) -- (x2) node[midway, anchor=east] {[.5]} node[midway, anchor=west] {D};
\draw (x1) -- (x3) node[midway, anchor=south] {R};
\draw (x1) -- (x5) node[midway, anchor=south] {L};
\draw (x2) -- (x4) node[midway, anchor=north] {r};
\draw (x2) -- (x6) node[midway, anchor=north] {l};
\draw (x5) -- (r1) node[near end, anchor=south west] {t};
\draw (x5) -- (r2) node[near end, anchor=north west] {b};
\draw (x6) -- (r3) node[near end, anchor=south west] {t};
\draw (x6) -- (r4) node[near end, anchor=north west] {b};
\draw[rounded corners=0.25em] ($(x6) - (0.25,0.75)$) rectangle ($(x5) + (0.25,0.75)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is based on the first, and is almost equally straightforward; the only difference is that the `calc` Ti*k*Z library is used for computing the coordinates of the rectangle (information set? I don't know too much about game theory) so that the rectangle will adapt automatically if the coordinates are changed. I've also used the occasional `xshift=` and `yshift=` to move labels around to match your picture more closely.

I hope that this can serve as a starting point for learning Ti*k*Z --- like LaTeX itself, it has a steep learning curve, but once you get the hang of it it's a very powerful tool.

Comment: Great, what about the second picture?

Comment: And please let me know to decrease the radios of Nature circle.

Comment: @Lisbeth I've made an edit to the code to make the Nature circle smaller --- for some reason you need to use `inner sep` there (I'm sure the resident Ti*k*Z experts can explain why this is, or suggest a better solution).

Comment: @Lisbeth added some code for the second as well.

Comment: @chsk: In order to draw the circle for Nature, you used a node with an empty content. While there is nothing to display, the node is not really empty because of the default `inner sep` which allows to let some space around the content in a node. By decreasing this `inner sep`, you decrease the size of the circle. If you want to increase it, it's better to use `minimum width` and `minimum height`. What you did is correct.

Comment: @SebGlav thanks, that's useful to know. Is there a way to use `\draw (o) circle[radius=...];` instead while still keeping the ability to later refer to `oc.75` etc.?

Comment: You can do this but it would not be considered a  node. Therefore, when drawing edges, they would not begin at the circle border. Node is the best way to achieve this kind of graphs, in my opinion.

Comment: @SebGlav exactly, that's why I used a node in the first place --- and why I had to use `inner sep=` (unintuitive) rather than `radius=` (more intuitive). Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Another try using the [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

**The first picture:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\setistNewNodeStyle{solid node}[null node]
\setistmathTF001
\setxtshowarrows[thick]
\xtShowArrows
\xtHideEndPoints
% game start
\setistgrowdirection'{east}
\xtdistance{10mm}{40mm}
\istroot(0)[chance node]<[xshift=2mm]200>{Nature}
  \istb{[.5]1}[l]
  \istb{[.5]2}[l]
  \endist
% right part
\xtdistance{30mm}{20mm}
\istroot(Ra)(0-1)<-45>{$x_1$}
  \istb{Average}[a] \endist
\istroot(Rb)(0-2)<45>{$x_2$}
  \istb{Average}[b] \endist
\xtdistance{20mm}{20mm}
\istroot(T1a)(Ra-1)<-135>{$x_3$}
  \istb{Hunk}[above,sloped]{2,3}
  \istb{Average}[below,sloped]{2,2}
  \endist
\istroot(T1b)(Rb-1)<135>{$x_4$}
  \istb{Hunk}[above,sloped]{2,3}
  \istb{Average}[below,sloped]{2,2}
  \endist
\xtInfoset[dashed](0-1)(0-2){$h_G$}[l]
\xtInfosetOwner(0-1)(0-2){Gina}[r]
\xtInfoset[dashed](T1a)(T1b){$h_{T1}$}[l]
\xtInfosetOwner(T1a)(T1b){Tina}[r]
% left part
\setistgrowdirection{west}
\xtdistance{30mm}{20mm}
\istroot(La)(0-1) \istb{Hunk}[a] \endist
\istroot(Lb)(0-2) \istb{Hunk}[b] \endist
\xtdistance{20mm}{20mm}
\istroot(T2a)(La-1)<-45>{$x_5$}
  \istb{Hunk}[above,sloped]{3,0}
  \istb{Average}[below,sloped]{3,2}
  \endist
\istroot(T2b)(Lb-1)<45>{$x_6$}
  \istb{Hunk}[above,sloped]{0,3}
  \istb{Average}[below,sloped]{3,2}
  \endist
\xtInfoset[dashed](T2a)(T2b){$h_{T2}$}[r]
\xtInfosetOwner(T2a)(T2b){Tina}[l]
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

**The second picture:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\setistNewNodeStyle{solid node}[null node]
\setistmathTF001
\xtdistance{20mm}{20mm}
\setistgrowdirection{west}
\istroot(0)[chance node]<0>{Nature}
  \istB<grow=90>[->]{[.5]}[l]{U}[r]
  \istB<grow=-90>[->]{[.5]}[l]{D}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(a)(0-1)<90>{2}
  \istb<grow=180>{L}[a]
  \istb<grow=0>{R}[a]{1,1}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(b)(0-2)<-90>{2}
  \istb<grow=180>{l}[b]
  \istb<grow=0>{r}[b]{1,1}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(T2a)(a-1)
  \istb{t}[a]{1,2}
  \istb{b}[b]{0,0}
  \endist
\istroot(T2b)(b-1)
  \istb{t}[a]{2,0}
  \istb{b}[b]{1,0}
  \endist
\xtInfosetO[rounded corners=5pt](T2a)(T2b){1}(2em)
\xtOwner(a){$x_u$}[br]
\xtOwner(b){$x_d$}[ar]
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am always agree this package when I see it :-) +1.